# Converting Javascript Array into String for Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to use an array i made to run .superslides function on

```
$(function() {
  $('#slides-1, #slides-2').superslides({
    hashchange: false
  });
});
```

here it is with the array i want to use

```
$(function() {
    $(slideShowArr).superslides({
        hashchange: false
    });
});
```

and, just in case, here is how the array was made

```
$(".slideshow").each(function(i, el){
    el.id = 'slides-' + (i + 1);
    slideShowArr.push('#' + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

so i need to pass slide show id's to .superslides function

Comment: Please don't forget to mention the framework you're working with whenever you do (I edited the tags of this question to reflect yours). 
This is important since the tag filtering system of stackoverflow relies on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `join` method of Array class to achieve this.

```
$(function() {
    $(slideShowArr.join(",")).superslides({
        hashchange: false
    });
});
```

Comment: Note: `slideShowAr.toString()` would give the same result as `slideShowArr.join(",")`

Comment: Thanks! It isn't quite working just yet but this is a lot closer

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you really want this:

```
$(function() {
    var slideShowArr = [];
    $(".slideshow").each(function(i, el){
        el.id = 'slides-' + (i + 1);
        slideShowArr.push('#' + $(this).attr('id'));
    });
    $(slideShowArr.join(", ")).superslides({
        hashchange: false
    });
});
```

because it makes absolutely no sense to iterate over a collection giving each item an id and then making a new selection from all the generated ids - just use the collection you already have! Better:

```
$(function() {
    $(".slideshow").prop("id", function(i) {
        return 'slides-' + (i + 1);
    }).superslides({
        hashchange: false
    });
});
```